# Magento 2: full page Mechanism

Tags: layout, magento2.4, full-page-cache, custom-block

I have a question. If full page is enable and If I  do not metioned below code in my block declareation layout xml file

```
<arguments>
   <argument name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="number">3600</argument>
</arguments>
```

So my custom block will be added in full page cache automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you **do not** specify `cache_lifetime` in your block layout your block will be cached by default.

If your block is inside another block it may inherit the cache rules for the parent block.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html